# Margin + ? = 100% width in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox with a width of `80vw` and content inside of it `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center`. All the items in the column have `28px` margin on either side. Right now, they are very skinny and only take up a part of the `80vw`. Inspecting it shows a large amount of whitespace on either side.

I still want stuff like text centered, but things like a selection box should take up the full width of the container (including margins).

I've read a few things on here, and I've tried setting `width: 100%` but that not only disregards the centering css (pushes the item all the way to the left) but also disregards margins, and the margins spill over out of the width of the container.

Finally, I tried `calc` and calculated `80vw - 28px` as the width of the inner content, but this did some weird stuff and only used half the margin, and the rest of it spilled out of the container.

[image]

```css
.outerContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.modalContainer {
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
 
.content1 {
  margin: 20px 28px 10px 28px;
  font-size: 27px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.content2 {
  margin: 10px 28px 20px 28px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="outerContainer">
      <div class="modalContainer">
        <div class="content1">
          Hello, World!
        </div>
        <div class="content2">
           <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just added the snippet. If you inspect element the text, you'll notice that it is not full width. (obviously, as I didn't include my failed attempts to do so) but that's what I want. Especially for the input to be full width (minus margin).

Comment: You have `28px` margin on either side. That's a total of `56px` you need to subtract in `calc`.

Comment: You're right. That's a dumb mistake. Unfortunately, this makes everything align to the left (albeit correct margins). I want the text and button (not in the snippet) to be in the center, but still have the input full width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the content divs 100% width minus margin by using the [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function  (comments added to the lines I changed below):

```css
.outerContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.modalContainer {
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
 
.content1 {
  margin: 20px 28px 10px 28px;
  font-size: 27px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.content2 {
  margin: 10px 28px 20px 28px;
  width: calc(100% - 56px);    /* 100% width minus 28px x 2 */
}


.content2 > input {
    width:100%;              /* make input stretch full width */
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="outerContainer">
      <div class="modalContainer">
        <div class="content1">
          Hello, World!
        </div>
        <div class="content2">
           <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should point out that if you also have text in the content 2 div, and you want that centred, just add `text-align:center` to `.content2`